# How to execute calculation in excel with aspen plus custom model?

Tags: excel, aspen

I'm using excel model to simulate membrane process. Due to many equations involved in the process, cubic equation solver has to be used. Every time I run aspen plus with different parameters, it does update the new values, but it won't solve when I switch to a calculation sheet until I hit enter key. Do I need to use VBA to allow the calculation to happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Aspen Simulation Workbook (ASW)](https://www.aspentech.com/en/products/pages/aspen-simulation-workbook) which installs with Aspen Engg. Suit by default and map your Aspen Plus Model with it. This is one time effort but once mapping is successful, you can run as many cases without even opening Aspen Plus software interface. ASW also enables to create excel trends and carryout detailed analysis by incorporating excel formulas on Aspen Plus results. All above is subjected to availability of ASW license with the user only. I hope this helps.